# How to retrieve (GET) data from a HTTPS self-signed webPage when I have public key, private key and ca file available?

Tags: c#, winforms, openssl, ssl-certificate, httpwebrequest

I am trying to GET some data from a https website and i do have credentials (both public and private key) along with the ca for the same. How can I do that?

I tried doing this and wasn't successful

```
private string RetrieveSoftwareDataMsgFromURL() {
            var cacert = File.ReadAllText(@"Certs\ca.crt");
            var clientcert = File.ReadAllText(@"Certs\client.crt");
            var clientkey = File.ReadAllText(@"Certs\client.key");

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 |SecurityProtocolType.Tls |SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };

            ICertificateProvider provider = new CertificateFromFileProvider(clientcert, clientkey);
            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = provider.Certificate;

            string url = "https://SomeWebsite.com/changelog";

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            httpWebRequest.AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequired;
            httpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
            httpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            string result = "Nothing's In There";
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
                result = streamReader.ReadLine();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

I ended up hitting this exception "System.Net.WebException: 'The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.' ".

Comment: `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;`, remove `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;`, remove `httpWebRequest.AuthenticationLevel = (...)` this is not a Kerberos auth. `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ...` remove all except `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`. Add `httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;`. Try to add the `User-Agent` header, using the IE11 default string (there's a reason): it's probably not required, add it anyway. The certificates formats and types depend on what the server is expecting, so does the method you use to add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't make it work with .crt and .key files, but tried by creating .pfx file with certs and then tried following;

```
        WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) { Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan };
        try {
            var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(URL) as HttpResponseMessage;
            using (var remoteStream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            using (var content = File.Create(filepath)) {
                var buffer = new byte[4096];
                int read;
                while ((read = await remoteStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0) {
                    await content.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    FlushFileBuffers(content.SafeFileHandle);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
        }
```